# I wanted to know whats the proper method to store list of datad and images in sqlite from parse.com android

Tags: android, sqlite, parse-platform

i have a query which gives me the list of  the parse object which i want to store in my sqlite database but my parseobject has images to so i am using **fileobject.getDataInBackground** to retrieve the images as soon i get the data from P**ublic void done(byte[] data, ParseException e)**  i run my sqlite query to save all the data to my database but it will only enter the last value in my sqlite database ,if any one any idea how can i store the list of contacts and images from parse.com to my sqlite database

```html
@Override
 protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  activity = (Activity) params[0];
  dh=new DataBaseHelper(activity);

  ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("PhoneNumber");
  query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

   @Override
   public void done(List<ParseObject> arg0, ParseException arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(arg0.size()>0)
    { 
     /*for(int i= 0;i<arg0.size();i++){*/
      //ParseObject object=arg0.get(i);
     for (ParseObject object : arg0){
      try{
       PhoneNumber =object.get("foo").toString();
      }catch(Exception e){}
      try{
       StatusTask = object.get("Status").toString();
      }catch(Exception e){}
      try{
       Name = object.get("Name").toString();
      }catch(Exception e){}
      try{
       ParseFile fileobject =(ParseFile) object.get("Profile_pic");
       
       fileobject.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
         if (e == null) {
          Log.d("test",
            "We've got data in data.");
          bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data , 0, data .length);
          User_photo = data ;
          
          } else {
          Log.d("test",
            "There was a problem downloading the data.");
         }
         
         if (dh.isProfileDataExist(PhoneNumber)) {
          if (dh.updateprofile(User_photo, PhoneNumber, Name, StatusTask) != -1)
           Log.d("isProfileDataExist",
             "Profile Data Updated");
         } else {
          if (dh.createProfile(User_photo, PhoneNumber, Name, StatusTask)!= -1) {
           Log.d("isProfileDataExist",
             "Profile Data Added");
          }
         }
        }
        
       });
      }catch(Exception e){}
      
     } 
    }
    else {
     Log.d("test",
       "There was a problem downloading the data.");
    }
   }
  });



  return null;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As from other post as i searched, i  found out that it was better to just fetch link for the parse image and store it in my database then from that link i can easily download and display the image using various library like  picasso and universal image loader